# handle triggering of another intent in alexa without completing first intent

Tags: chatbot, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I have two intents (HelloWorldIntent and PlaceOrderIntent) in my first intent is about hello world and in second intent I am placing order (for this I need to fill slots)

```
user: open demo bot
Alexa: welcome!
user: place order
alexa: you can order platter, soup, and shake?
user: soup
alexa: which type of soup? tomato, onion or corn?
user: tomato
alexa: your order for tomato soup has been placed.
```

this works fine but if the user triggers HelloWorldIntent in between PlaceOrderIntent then it gets triggered, how to avoid this

```
user: open demo bot
alexa: welcome!
user: place order
alexa: you can order platter, soup and shake?
user : hello
alexa: hello world!
```

without completing the PlaceOrderIntent another intent gets triggered instead of showing reprompt message.

this is my code

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'HelloWorldIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const speakOutput = 'Hello World!';
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt()
            .getResponse();
    }
};

const StartedInProgressOrderFoodIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "PlaceOrderIntent"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED'
      && !handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value;
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
  const speakOutput = `You can order Platters, Soups and, Shakes. What you want to order?`
  const prompt = `Please select any one from platter, soup or, drink.`
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .reprompt(prompt)
      .addElicitSlotDirective('menu')
      .getResponse();
  }
};

const PlatterGivenOrderFoodIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "PlaceOrderIntent"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value 
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value === 'platter'
      && !handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.platType.value;
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speakOutput = `Which platter would you like Regular, Special, Rajasthani, Gujarati, or Punjabi?`
    const prompt = `Which platter would you like Regular, Special, Rajasthani, Gujarati, or Punjabi?`
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speakOutput)
      .reprompt(prompt)
      .addElicitSlotDirective('platType')
      .getResponse();
  }
};

const SoupGivenOrderFoodIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "PlaceOrderIntent"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value === 'soup'
      && !handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.soupType.value;
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak("Which soup would you like tomato, manchow, onion, or corn soup?")
      .reprompt("Would you like a tomato, manchow, onion, or corn soup?")
      .addElicitSlotDirective('soupType')
      .getResponse();
  }
};

const ShakeGivenOrderFoodIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "PlaceOrderIntent"
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value === 'shake'
      && !handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.shakeType.value;
      },
  handle(handlerInput) {
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak("Which shake would you like chocolate, vanilla, milk, strawberry, or mango shake?")
      .reprompt("Would you like a chocolate, vanilla, milk, strawberry, or mango shake?")
      .addElicitSlotDirective('shakeType')
      .getResponse();
  }
};

const CompletedOrderFoodIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest"
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "PlaceOrderIntent"
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState === "COMPLETED"
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value
        || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.platType.value || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.soupType.value || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.shakeType.value;
  },
  handle(handlerInput){

    const menuitems = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value;
    let type; 

    if (menuitems === 'platter') {
        type = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.platType.value;
    } else if (menuitems === 'soup') {
        type = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.soupType.value;
    } else if (menuitems === 'shake') {
        type = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.shakeType.value;
    } else {
        type = 'water'
    }

    const speechText = `Your order for ${type} ${menuitems} has been placed.`;
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText)
        .reprompt()
        .getResponse();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a state machine.

Here's a for instance...

- Set a `state = started` sessionVariable when entering the step you want to lock. *i.e., StartedInProgress*

```
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes({state: "started"});
```

- Now you only "unset" `state` in your `OrderFood` intents.

```
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes({state: ""});
```

- Finally, if you register `StartedInProcess…` first (search for `addRequestHandlers` in your `index.js` file), and set that intent's `canHandle` to include a "state is start and not one of the OrderFood intents" it will always fire if you're in that state but not trying to order.

```
const StartedInProgressOrderFoodIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
      const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
      hasStarted = sessionAttributes.state == "started"
      isOrdering = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name.includes('GivenOrder')
      return (hasStarted and !isOrdering) or (
        handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "IntentRequest"
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === "PlaceOrderIntent"
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED'
        && !handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.menu.value);
    }
  …
```

Realize that this means your users will be LOCKED into the process… unless you register another intent (say, Exit?) before `StartedInProcess` that can clear `state`—which I highly recommend.

Comment: thanks, @Timothy Aaron for helping but I am new, so can you please show me how the code should look like when your steps are followed.

Comment: I tried. I use the Python SDK, so my JS (not to mention Alexa NodeJS SDK) skills are lacking... but that should at least give you enough details to get the majority of the way. Good luck.